# SQL - Select two different conditions on same record

Tags: php, sql

I need to check if a record is either 0 or higher/equal current time. For this IN doesn't work, anyone have an idea?

This is my SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM domains WHERE tld='dk' AND whoisexpire !='' AND (whoisupdate='0' OR whoisupdate>='".time()."') AND majrefd>=25 AND majtf>=10 ORDER BY whoisexpire LIMIT 25";
```

Updated SQL line (removed quotes around integer value)

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE tld='dk' AND whoisexpire !='' AND (whoisupdate=0 OR whoisupdate>=".time().") AND majrefd>=25 AND majtf>=10 ORDER BY whoisexpire LIMIT 25
```

To clarify some things up, the issue is that it keeps returning the same domains, even though a record does not match with the SQL `OR whoisupdate>=".time()."`

Comment: `OR` should work the way you've written it, assuming the time is stored as a timestamp integer.

Comment: If it's an integer, don't quote the value.

Comment: Try `whoisupdate='0' OR whoisupdate>=NOW()`

Comment: It indeed is stored as timestamp integer, but when I run the script it still checks the same domains - unless the ones it can detect changes on successfully - which is weird, because it updates whoisupdate, which sets it 30 days ahead, but the sql still gets it.

Comment: Tried to remove the quotes as mentioned, but it still returns same domains, even when a condition does not match sql line.

Comment: @JDoe i believe you haven't tried my above solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM domains 
        WHERE tld='dk' 
          AND whoisexpire !='' 
          AND (whoisupdate = 0 OR whoisupdate >= NOW()) 
          AND majrefd>=25 
          AND majtf>=10 
        ORDER BY whoisexpire 
        LIMIT 25";
```

Comment: This seems to work, it doesn't get same domains that are already checked. Thanks to you and @Mahesh. Do you have an idea why NOW() works, but not time() ?

Comment: This may be caused by many reasons. Say, time difference between PHP server (`time()` depends on it) and MySQL server (which has its own internal `NOW()`)

Comment: `NOW()` returns a `DATETIME`, he said in the comments that `whoisupdate` is an `INT`. Shouldn't that be `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead?